# Product of Two Correlated Brownian Motions

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, variance

Suppose that $W_{1,t}$ is a Brownian Motion and $W_{2,t}$ is another Brownian Motion. The two Brownian Motions have correlation equal to $\rho$.

Let C = $W_{1,t} \cdot W_{2,t}$

What is the distribution of $C$?

I did make this up - so no guarantees there's a solution...but I feel like there should be!

I was able to get $E(C) = \rho t$ and I know $dW_{1,t} \cdot dW_{2,t} = \rho dt$

Any advice? Is $C$ normally distributed? Can the variance be computed too?

Comment: I got $V(C) = 2t^{2} \rho^{2} + (1 - \rho^{2}) t^{2}$. Does that sound right?

Comment: A hint: given two Gaussian variables, $X$ and $Y$, what is the distribution of their product?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm asking. I did some research - and my understanding is that there is not a simple answer to that question in general. Products of correlated normals are not necessarily normal

Comment: Precisely.  $C$ does not have a closed form distribution.

Comment: The PDF of $C$ is $$f_C(x)=\frac1{2\pi \sqrt{ts}}\exp\left(-\frac{\rho x}s\right)\int_0^\infty\exp\left(-\frac{|x|}{2s}\left(\frac1y+y\right)\right)\frac{dy}y$$ where $$s=(1-\rho^2)t$$